# How to elegantly swap out (patch) a Django FileSystemStorage setting in your unit tests?

Tags: django, unit-testing, settings, storage, patch

I'm faced with the following problem.  I have a Model that looks somewhat like this:

```
class Package(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="subdir",
                            storage=settings.PACKAGE_STORAGE,
                            null=True)
```

Essential in this example is the `storage=` argument to the `FileField` constructor.  It is filled with a value from `settings.py`.  In there is the following code:

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
PACKAGE_STORAGE = FileSystemStorage(location="/var/data", base_url="/")
```

For production use, this works fine. But in my unit tests, uploads I make are now written to `/var/data`, which contains production data. I tried to swap out the `PACKAGE_STORE` in `packages/tests.py` like this

```
from django.conf import settings     # This is line 1
from tempfile import mkdtemp
settings.PACKAGE_STORAGE = FileSystemStorage(location=mkdtemp(), base_url="/")

# rest of the imports and testing code below
```

but the real problem is that **before** the test file is loaded, the `packages` app and its models have been loaded already, and therefore, the `PACKAGE_STORAGE` setting has been resolved before I'm able to change it in the test setup code.

Is there an elegant way to override this specific setting in a testing context?

Comment: To supplement: I've tried lazy evaluation on the `location` and the `storage` arguments, but it didn't help: `FileSystemStorage` immediately evaluates any lazy `location=` argument by calling `.startswith()` on it and `FileField` immediately evaluates any lazy `storage=` argument by calling `.get_valid_name()` on it.

Comment: What is `PACKAGE_STORAGE`?

Answer (score 10):

Don't know if this counts as elegant, but you could use a different settings file for testing...

Something like:

```
# test_settings.py

from settings import *

PACKAGE_STORAGE = FileSystemStorage(location='/test/files', base_url="/")
```

Then run your test using the test settings, `python manage.py test --settings=test_settings`.

Comment: You kidding yourself @meshantz!? This is as elegant as it gets. Not the only way, but defo the most elegant.

Comment: @kRON thanks. I just fear that using different settings files can lead to abuse, and unfortunate test wide side effects. If you're not careful what you put in the overrides.

Comment: I did not know about --settings param for django test, thx :)

Comment: I like this one the most. However, this still requires the discipline to always add the `--settings=test_settings` argument. If you forget to add it, production data may easily be wiped or modified.

Comment: and @Vincent, I always have three settings files, `production.py`, `settings.py` and `test.py`. `settings.py` contains development settings, and if run by default, specifies database settings that do not exist in the production environment which causes the test runner to fail immediately, which forces you to use `--settings` in production for any command you run. Just pay attention with test storages--Django will always create a `test_` database not to intermingle with the production data in the DB, but it cant save you from physically changing data in your storages accidentally.

Answer (score 5):

if you run the test through django this should work

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    settings.DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = FileSystemStorage(location=mkdtemp(), base_url="/")
```

of course after ;)

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = FileSystemStorage(location="/var/data", base_url="/")
```

Comment: Although I think the test for the `argv` value is pretty ugly, this is at least a solution that does not require the discipline to remember the alternate settings file.

Comment: @Flimm I meant DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE

Answer (score 5):

Override the underlying storage implementation for instances of `FileField` on your model dynamically:

```
def setUp(self):
     self._field = Package._meta.get_field_by_name('file')[0]
     self._default_storage = self._field.storage
     test_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=mkdtemp(),
                                      base_url="/")

     self._field.storage = test_storage

def tearDown(self):
     self._field = self._default_storage
```

Answer (score 3):

I just solved this by adding to my custom test runner. To see how to add a custom test runner, see [Defining a test runner](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/?from=olddocs#defining-a-test-runner) in the Django documentation. My code looks something like this:

```
import shutil
import tempfile
from django.test.simple import DjangoTestSuiteRunner
from django.conf import settings

class CustomTestRunner(DjangoTestSuiteRunner):

    def setup_test_environment(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomTestRunner, self).setup_test_environment(**kwargs)
        self.backup = {}
        self.backup['DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE'] = settings.DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE
        settings.DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
        self.backup['MEDIA_ROOT'] = settings.MEDIA_ROOT
        self.temp_media_root = tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix="myapp-tests")
        settings.MEDIA_ROOT = self.temp_media_root

    def teardown_test_environment(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomTestRunner, self).teardown_test_environment(**kwargs)
        for name, value in self.backup.iteritems():
            setattr(settings, name, value)

    def run_tests(self, test_labels, **kwargs):
        try:
            test_results = super(CustomTestRunner, self).run_tests(test_labels, **kwargs)
        finally:
            shutil.rmtree(self.temp_media_root, ignore_errors=True)
```

This overrides some of the custom test suite methods. `setup_test_environment` backs up the previous settings and stores them in a class attribute. The `teardown_test_environment` sets them back to what they were before. The `run_tests` method uses a try/finally block to make sure that the temporary directory is deleted after the tests, even if an exception happens.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `pytest-django` and want to keep a single Django configuration file you can create a `conftest.py` and have that setting overridden for every test executed ([source](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuring_django.html#overriding-individual-settings))

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def use_file_system_storage(settings):
    settings.PACKAGE_STORAGE = FileSystemStorage(location=mkdtemp(), base_url="/")
```

You can also change your app before Django sets up using `pytest-django`. See [here](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuring_django.html#changing-your-app-before-django-gets-set-up).

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but it took me a long time to find this nice little library;

https://pypi.org/project/django-override-storage/

Answer (score 0):

For prod we use a s3 and boto3 but for unit tests it is enough to use great lib [dj-inmemorystorage](https://github.com/waveaccounting/dj-inmemorystorage) which just loads the file to memory.
So, I just override the default file storage in my test settings:

```py
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'inmemorystorage.InMemoryStorage'
```

then in the test:

```py
record.receipt_file = SimpleUploadedFile('receipt.txt', b'')
```